# joining specific indexs in a string array

Tags: arrays, vb.net, string

in a vb.ne application i have a string array that looks like the following

```
dim s1() as array = {"vase",  "kalr", "7", "cm", "blue"}
```

so is there a bult in function that will make it look like the following by specifying the indexs i want to join?

```
{"vase",  "kalr", "7cm", "blue"}
```

i have alot of such cases where sometimes i need to join 4 indexs togather depending on some conditions , so whats the best way to do such things?

another more complicated example

```
{"vase",  "kalr", "7x" , "12" , "cm", "blue"}
```

need it tol look like

```
{"vase",  "kalr", "7x12cm", "blue"}
```

Comment: You must be having some specific condition on which you want to merge the strings. Please share that otherwise it would be difficult to predict your requirement.

Comment: i have the conditions, but my question is there a function to join them?

Comment: I think you need to use concatenation of string based on your condition and output the resulting values into a new array.

Comment: this is what i am already doing, but isnt there a better way?

Comment: Without knowing your specific conditions for joining the array values, I would say it would be easiest to just concatenate the values you need joined together in a new array.

Comment: @Chris i ended up using this and its working fine